# trying to center html divs on a page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center div tags on a page (content inside is irrelevant).  I am able to do it and the page looks great, but it's completely hacked together with arbitrary margins everywhere to get things to align correctly.  Can someone point me to a simple .css solution to pull of a page with a structure that looks something like the attached image?

[image]

Comment: Flex. Definitely flex.

Comment: Flex it baby ;)

Comment: css grids e.g. bootstrap. flex still is not universal (mobile safari?)

Comment: Flex doesn't work, or work well, in IE. Flex should not be used for page layout, either. That's not what it's for. Seems, nowadays, flex is everyone's solution to everything including bed wetting and marriage issues. And the suggestion for CSS grids is worse as it's only available in the newest of browsers and has problems in Edge (as always expected).

Comment: bootstrap is polyfilled. works in prehistory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use plain CSS without flex or grid layout. Here is an example using Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block row"></div>
  <div class="clearfix row row2">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col"><div class="block"></div></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col"><div class="block"></div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block row"></div>
  <div class="clearfix row row4">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col"><div class="block"></div></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col"><div class="block"></div></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col"><div class="block"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>

.block {
  background: blue;
  height: 30px;
}
.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.row .col:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.row .col:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.row4 .col {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/j6xsrucm/5/).

Comment: Now that is clean.....  thank you....

Comment: @ shaochuancs - is there a way to do this without having to specify heights for everything?  This would be perfect if I could put content inside of it and have it automatically size.

Comment: yes, the `.block`'s height can be dynamically decided by its content. Please check: https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/j6xsrucm/7/ Please note I use `height: 100%` for `.block` to make blocks horizontally align.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **percentage** width, associated with **float** property, to do what you want.

**Float**: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

For example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="second-container">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="third-container">
</div>
<div class="fourth-container">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
  .header{
    width:90%; 
    height:50px; 
    margin:5%; 
    background-color:blue;
  }

  .second-container{
    height:80px; 
    width:90%;
    margin:5%;
  }

  .second-container .left{
    height:100%; 
    width:40%; 
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
    float:left; 
    background-color:blue;
  }

  .second-container .right{
    height:100%;
    width:40%; 
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
    float:left; 
    background-color:blue;
  }

  .third-container{
    height:50px;
    width:90%;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:5%;
  }

  .fourth-container{
    height:70px;
    width:90%;
    margin:5%;
  }

  .fourth-container .left{
    background-color:blue;
    height:100%;
    width:29%;
    margin-right:2%;
    margin-left:2%;
    float:left;
  }

  .fourth-container .middle{
    background-color:blue;
    height:100%;
    width:30%;
    margin-right:2%;
    margin-left:2%;
    float:left;
  }

  .fourth-container .right{
    background-color:blue;
    height:100%;
    width:29%;
    margin-right:2%;
    margin-left:2%;
    float:left;
  }
```

Of course, you can play with the values of margin if you want to adjust the way you want. Just take care of having 100% in total for a same line if you want it to look nice.

**JSFiddle here** : https://jsfiddle.net/zg1u2dnu/

Answer (score 0):

Well... There are many ways to get this result. If you want to do it with pure HTML/CSS, **Flexbox** is probably the most convenient solution:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#wrapper > div {
  margin: 10px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #4F81BD;
}

#top, #middle-bottom {
  height: 100px;
}

#middle-top, #bottom {
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#middle-top > div {
  width: 45%;
}

#bottom > div {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Flexbox demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top" class="blue"></div>
    <div id="middle-top">
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="middle-bottom" class="blue"></div>
    <div id="bottom">
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**However, like Vanilla JS, this will not work as expected in all web browsers... I recommend you to use front-end frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/) for optimal results.**